# Flex. Zoom Canvas using the matrix

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, matrix

**Hi, I was wondering how you can use the matrix to increase the component of the canvas!
If possible, show the code for the study)**

Comment: "the component of the canvas" can mean several things. Please clarify.

Comment: **I need to change the size of Canvas with a slider, and the amount of canvas greater than the parent component that would appear scrolling**

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to explore [corresponding documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html?filter_flex=4.5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2.5#translate%28%29).

Then you can try the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application layout="absolute" minHeight="600" minWidth="955" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        /**
         * Stores the button size multiplier on roll over.
         */
        public static const SIZE_MULTIPLIER:Number = 2.5;

        /**
         * Stores initial button's transfrom matrix.
         */
        private var buttonMatrix:Matrix;

        protected function zoomedButton_rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var zoomedButton:Button = event.currentTarget as Button;
            // Get initial button transform matrix
            var matrix:Matrix = zoomedButton.transform.matrix;
            buttonMatrix = matrix.clone();
            // Modify matrix to move button's center to the Canvas (0, 0) point. 
            matrix.translate(-zoomedButton.width / 2 - zoomedButton.x,
                -zoomedButton.height / 2 - zoomedButton.y);
            // Modify matrix to scale using multiplier value
            matrix.scale(SIZE_MULTIPLIER, SIZE_MULTIPLIER);
            // Modify matrix to return button back
            matrix.translate(zoomedButton.width / 2 + zoomedButton.x,
                zoomedButton.height / 2 + zoomedButton.y);
            // Apply resulting matrix
            zoomedButton.transform.matrix = matrix;
        }

        protected function zoomedButton_rollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var zoomedButton:Button = event.currentTarget as Button;
            // Restore buttons position
            zoomedButton.transform.matrix = buttonMatrix;
        }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Panel height="50%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" width="50%" layout="absolute">
        <mx:Button label="Test" rollOut="zoomedButton_rollOutHandler(event)"
            rollOver="zoomedButton_rollOverHandler(event)" x="100" y="50" />
    </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

I used the Panel with layout="absolute" for illustrating purposes but it is the same as Canvas (so you can use Canvas without any problem).

And of course you can use concat() method to form the matrix and consider scale() and translate() methods as shortcuts:

```
        protected function zoomedButton_rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var zoomedButton:Button = event.currentTarget as Button;
            var matrix:Matrix = zoomedButton.transform.matrix;
            buttonMatrix = matrix.clone();
            matrix.
                concat(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -zoomedButton.width / 2 - zoomedButton.x,
                                  -zoomedButton.height / 2 - zoomedButton.y));
            matrix.concat(new Matrix(SIZE_MULTIPLIER, 0, 0, SIZE_MULTIPLIER));
            matrix.
                concat(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, zoomedButton.width / 2 + zoomedButton.x,
                                  zoomedButton.height / 2 + zoomedButton.y));
            zoomedButton.transform.matrix = matrix;
        }
```

Hope this helps :)